# RPM Requires exact release tag

Tags: maven, rpm, centos6, yum

I'm working on a Java project were each module creates individual rpm packages that always have a *1.0* Version tag, but the Release tag adopts the build number injected by Jenkins CI.

Each component uses the maven-rpm-plugin.

There's also a *main* rpm package were we specify the exact version of the deployed modules as requirements in the **spec** file, as a requirement example:

> Requires: module1 = 1.0-10
>
> Requires: module2 = 1.0-123

The packages are deployed to the company's repository and are made available to our development machines that run CentOS 6.

So the issue is:

On one dev machine, the previous *main* package installed **module1-1.0-9**

When I install the current *main* package version using yum, module1 **does not get upgraded**, even though I specified an **exact** package version requirement, down to the Release tag.

After removing all packages and trying to install the current *main* package, **module1-1.0-12** get's installed! Another module build was deployed in the meantime.

I've been looking for any kind of documentation about this but haven't had any luck.

Is this normal behavior or a bug?

Any ideas? - even changing versioning strategy would be welcome, if it's indeed not a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After another day trying to get to the bottom of this I finally stumbled across this bug report in [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=902793).

I also took a look at the yum related [source code](http://yum.baseurl.org/) and found a comment on the **depsolve.py** module that explains how dependencies are resolved and corroborates the previously reported behavior in CentOS 6:

1. If you're installing a package and a required packaged is found, the latest version is installed
2. If you're updating a package and a required package is already installed, there is no dependency upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Is the package name changing somehow?  Yum uses the name, version and the release.  So if you are packaging with a different name then yum is not going to see the newer package as an update to the old one.

Do an `rpm -qip *your-rpm-file-name.rpm*` and compare the output of the name.  I've seen in the past some people get confused with the file name of the RPM and actual name of the RPM that yum/rpm uses.

Comment: I tried that and they returned the correct name, version, release and architecture on the rpm filename. I'm suspecting yum repo metadata but I'm yet to have access to that.

Comment: Do you have a test machine that you can create a repo on?  Then you can test that theory on a box you control.